# In IE style tags dont allow the use of classes, but do they allow custom attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I was creating a dynamic design for style-sheets, essentially allowing a user to define a class and style data in a textarea.  I was then referencing these items in CHROME with classes. I was doing this to populate DDLs for quick reference later.

I was told that IE doesnt like the "class" attribute being used on style tags because then styles could reference themselves or something along those lines.

My question is:  Can i use Custom Attributes in IE Style tags as an alternative?  Would IE accept that?

Instead of doing:

```
$("style.mycustomClass").each(...);
```

I could do:

```
$("style[customAttr='mycustomClass']").each(...);
```

to get the same effect i am looking for?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Just try it and see. You could also use Id ("style#someId")

Comment: I cant use ID because there will be an array of style tags being created.  Ill have 5 style tags or more... or less, and want to be able to select the entire list so i can walk it for particular data

Comment: Custom attributes, specifically `data-*`, should be fine to target the elements

Comment: If the reason classes can't be used is the css in the style tag can reference itself, why would that be any different for attributes or the id? *confused*

Comment: So what if it can reference itself? the worst thing you could do is set display: block, which might make the contents visible (used to do that on script tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sample works using custom Attributes (in IE9,10, Edge emulation ):

http://jsfiddle.net/WuCDq/

```
$("style[customAttr='win']").each(...);
```

this one also seems to work, using classes( in IE9,10,Edge emulation ):

http://jsfiddle.net/FZtjF/

```
$("style.customAttr").each(...);
```

I have no idea what my colleague was talking about.  Sorry guys.  Ill close this.